# Websphere EL error jspg0122e

Tags: jsp, jstl, websphere, el

Java objects can be accessed in jsp using EL.

```
alert(${requestBean.getData()});
//This statement is throwing error JSPG0122e
```

jstl library has been included and object requestBean has values, using Websphere v6.1.
What might be the possible error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere v6.1 is too old. It supports only J2EE 1.4. You can only use properties of your bean, not any arbitrary method in EL. This is supported in Java EE 5 (JSP 2.0) which would be since WebSphere 7.0.

You could try `requestBean.data` if you have get/setData methods in your bean.